# Correct way to dig a hole in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

I was trying to dig a hole in a sphere. But Draw tool only allows me to get this deep:

[image]

I turned on Dyntopo, but it doesn't help much and increases polycon like crazy:

[image]

I know it's probably easier to start with a tube/cylinder. But just for learning purposes, is there a proper way to sculpt something like this?

Comment: do you mean that you want the hole to pass through the object?

Comment: @moonboots yeah, something like a donut

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's the *Lasso Trim* (and *Box Trim*) brush that can dig a hole, I'm not sure there's any other tool for the moment (it is lacking imho):

[image]

[image]

Markus von Broady makes me think about another solution, but it's in *Edit* mode so it doesn't properly answer to your question: you can select opposite faces and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, it will dig a hole through your object (or use right click > *LoopTools > Bridge*):

[image]

Comment: Why are the inner faces in a different color?

Comment: it creates Face Sets (I don't know why) but you can go in the Face Sets panel > Initialize Face Sets > By Loose Parts

Comment: ohhhh I get it now

Answer (score 9):

You can try the blob brush, holding Ctrl to invert its behaviour (or setting it to "subtract").

[image]

Answer (score 5):

How about going to <kbd>Tab</kbd> Edit mode to <kbd>E</kbd> extrude, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> add loopcuts for an even density of topology to work in further?

[image]